# Sum on columns with the same ID and different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sum

Using Microsoft SQL Server

I need to create a table that takes the User IDs from the temp table. Collects only those User IDs and then adds all of the Points for that individual user together.

Temp table which pulled all the most recent records for each User ID.

```
User ID | Points | Date Field   
-----------------------------
1           1      10/31/2016       
3           1      08/26/2016
```

Main

```
User ID | Points | Date Field  | Other Field
--------------------------------------------
 1          1      10/31/2016      N/A
 1          2      10/25/2016      N/A      
 1          3      09/18/2016      N/A     
 2          1      08/17/2017      N/A     
 2         16      07/11/2017      N/A     
 3          1      08/27/2016      N/A       
 3          5      05/14/2016      N/A
```

So take temp table and match those User IDs to the main table. From that data you should only have collected those which match the record IDs in the temp table. From there the report will then be broken down to look like below. Which shows the most recent date, and a sum of all the points for that User ID.

```
User ID  | Points | Date Field  | Other Field
---------------------------------------------
  1         6      10/31/2016       N/A  
  3         6      08/27/2016       N/A
```

I tried this SQL:

```
SELECT
    a.[User ID], a.[Points], a.[Date Field], a.[Other Field1], a.[Other Field2], a.[Other Field3], 
    (CASE WHEN b.[User ID] = a.[User ID] THEN SUM(a.Points) END) AS [Total Points]
FROM
    Main_Table a
INNER JOIN
    #Temp b ON b.[User ID] = a.[User ID]
GROUP BY 
    a.[User ID], [Points], [Date Field], [Other Field1], [Other Field2], [Other Field3]
```

I get the total points column, but is not adding all the fields with identical User IDs together.

I just need to know where I am going wrong. I'm not the best with SQL and I'm still learning. Please understand I am trying my best to figure this out.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Marc_s. I was trying to figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine something like this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    b.[User ID]
    , b.[Points]
    , b.[Date Field]
    , SUM(a.Points) [Total Points]
FROM
    #Temp b
    INNER JOIN Main_Table a ON b.[User ID] = a.[User ID]
GROUP BY
    b.[User ID]
    , b.[Points]
    , b.[Date Field]
```

But then the question would be, which of the other fields from Main_Table do you want to keep?

I imagine possibly something like this:

```
SELECT
    b.[User ID]
    , b.[Points]
    , b.[Date Field]
    , m.[Other_Field] -- etc.
    , SUM(a.Points) [Total Points]
FROM
    #Temp b
    INNER JOIN Main_Table m ON
        b.[User ID] = m.[User ID]
        AND b.[Date Field] = m.[Date Field]
    INNER JOIN Main_Table a ON b.[User ID] = a.[User ID]
GROUP BY
    b.[User ID]
    , b.[Points]
    , b.[Date Field]
    , m.[Other_Field]
```

Comment: I need to keep all the fields from the main table. I just tried running this. It is still not adding together the points from alike User IDs. It is actually keeping them in their own seperate records.

Comment: The issue would be that you're summing the points in Main_Table, so you can't keep all of the records from the other fields.

Comment: So because I'm not using all of the fields, if there are variances in the records then it won't add together? Then would I just make a table which just has the user id, points, and date I need? Or will the date variances also interfere?

Comment: In the query I've written, the dates will be OK, because they are coming from #Temp, i.e. 1 record per User ID. In the second query, the first join is intended to return only the User IDs and dates that match, so can pull in 1 matching record from the additional fields on that basis (if that's what you need).

Comment: The second query bogged our system down, so I had to cancel it out. I'm unsure if it will work or not. It was running for about 19 minutes before I had to cancel it.
I'll try again at another time.
Thank you for explaining your methods. It was really beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

To get Sum, you have to group by fields that are non-changing. So User ID is the non-changing field you would want to SUM by. The group by is done to this non-aggregate field User ID.  The problem with date and [Other Field] is that they are changing often. This defeats the group by. You have to query back to the original table to get the max date field if that's your intent. I'm not sure what [Other Field] are, but you have to take into account if they are different changing values.

```
SELECT dT.[User ID]
      ,dT.Points
      ,(SELECT MAX([Date Field]) 
          FROM #main M2 
         WHERE M2.[User ID] = dT.[User ID]) AS [Date Field]
  FROM (
         SELECT M.[User ID]
               ,SUM(M.Points) AS Points   
           FROM #main M
          WHERE [User ID] IN (SELECT [User ID] FROM #temp)
         GROUP BY M.[User ID]
       ) AS dT
```

Creates output:

```
User ID Points  Date Field
1       6       2016-10-31
3       6       2016-08-27
```

Comment: That was actually really informative.  Thank You!
 The Other fields do have changing data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this should help

```
--======================= CREATE TEMP TABLE==============================
          CREATE TABLE #TEMP ([USER ID] INT,    
                            POINTS INT,
                            [DATE FIELD] DATE)
--======================= VALUES ON THE TABLE ===============================
          INSERT INTO #TEMP  VALUES ( 1 ,1,'10-31-2016')
          INSERT INTO #TEMP  VALUES  (3,1,'08-26-2016')
    --======================== CREATE MAIN TABLE ============================
          CREATE TABLE #MAIN ([USER ID] INT,
                            POINTS INT,
                            [DATE FIELD] DATE,
                            [OTHER FIELD] NVARCHAR(50))
     --======================= VALUES ON MAIN TABLE===================
        INSERT INTO #MAIN  VALUES ( 1,1,'10-31-2016','N/A')
        INSERT INTO #MAIN  VALUES ( 1,2,'10-25-2016','N/A')
        INSERT INTO #MAIN  VALUES ( 1,3,'09-18-2016','N/A')
        INSERT INTO #MAIN  VALUES ( 2,1,'08-17-2017','N/A')
        INSERT INTO #MAIN  VALUES ( 2,16,'07-11-2017','N/A')
        INSERT INTO #MAIN  VALUES ( 3,1,'08-27-2016','N/A')
        INSERT INTO #MAIN  VALUES ( 3,5,'05-14-2016','N/A')
     --=====GETTING SUM OF YOUR POINTS=====
        SELECT  T2.[USER ID],
                SUM(T1.[POINTS]) AS [TOTAL POINT],
                T2.[DATE FIELD],
                T1.[OTHER FIELD]
        FROM #MAIN AS T1
        RIGHT JOIN #TEMP AS T2
        ON T1.[USER ID] = T2.[USER ID]
        GROUP BY T2.[USER ID],
                 T2.[DATE FIELD],
                 T1.[OTHER FIELD]

        DROP TABLE #TEMP
        DROP TABLE #MAIN
```